# Assembly language programming using nasm alongwith c library

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

can anyone explain me the code with stack?The below given code is supposed to be for printing command line argument then adding 1 to it and again print it.
But I am totally confused because of stack working in this case.
And i think there is some mistake in code.

```
SECTION .data
msg:db"You Entered -%s", 10, 0; print argv[1] data
msg2:db"This is int-%d", 10, 0; print INT equivalent

SECTION .text
extern printf
extern atoi
global main
main:
; set-up phase

push ebp
mov ebp, esp

; get the command-line data

mov ebx, DWORD [esp+ 12]           ; get argvstarting address
mov ebx, [ebx+ 4]                    ; get the second argument data

; print the value

push ebx                               ; put data on stack for call
push msg                               ; print the value
call printf

; convert to integer

add esp, 4                           ; stack points to entry edx
call atoi                           ; call atoi-return in EAX?

; get return value and add 1

add esp, 4                          ; esppoints to start
inc eax                             ; increase eaxfor testing

; print the result

push eax                           ; push argfor print
push msg2                         ; push print message
call printf

; finish phase

add esp, 8                        ; esp back to start
movesp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening here is that the code is "pushing" something onto the stack, or in a high level language, giving the function printf the parameters it needs to do it's job. Once printf() is called once, the variable is turned into an integer, incremented, and printf() is called again. The stack is added to because there are other elements. For example, if I pushed 2 elements onto the stack, and I want to get the element I pushed on to the stack before I pushed the 2nd element, then I would need to add/subtract to the stack.